# How to make python multiple conditions into a single statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, conditional-statements

How to make the method below be returned in a single line?

Prefer to the #Note  ## remarks below.

```
def falsify(leftover):
    #Note   ## Your code here (replace with a single line) ###
     
def falsify(leftover):
    false = []
    for num in leftover:
        if 30 > num > 20:
            false.append(num - 10)
        elif num >= 30:
            false.append('1' + (str(num[1:])))
        else:
            false.append(num)
     return false
```

I don't have any other idea except breaking into 2 methods.

```
leftover1 = [19.7, 20.0, 28.5, 30.0, 30.7]

def process(leftover):
    false = []
    for num in leftover:
        print('num:' , num)

        if 30 > num >= 20: false.append(num - 10) 
        elif num >= 30:            
            # (str(num[1]))
            result = str(num)
            #print('result:' , result)
            false.append('1' + result[1:])
            #
        else:
            false.append(num)
    return false 


def falsify(leftover):
    #Note  ## Your code here (replace with a single line) ###
    return process(leftover)

print('result', falsify(leftover1))
```

Sample output as below

```
num: 19.7
num: 20.0
num: 28.5
num: 30.0
num: 30.7
result [19.7, 10.0, 18.5, '10.0', '10.7']
```

Comment: why did u need that?

Comment: Your first code fragment is broken due to TypeError. It's unclear exactly what your second code fragment is hoping to achieve. This needs more clarity. Sample input and expected output would help

Comment: @LucasBorges-Santos learning new technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
leftover = [19.7, 20.0, 28.5, 30.0, 30.7]
def falsify(leftover):
    return [num - 10 if 30 > num >= 20 else ('1' + str(num)[1:]) if num >= 30 else num for num in leftover]

print('result', falsify(leftover))

# output
#result [19.7, 10.0, 18.5, '10.0', '10.7']
```

Comment: what is benefit of using this way and making complex thing into single line ? it's gonna be crazy to be debugged especially handle by another person  or gonna explain how to build an car engine in a single statement

Comment: hmm.. yes you are right

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with list comprehension:

```
def falsify(leftover): 
    return [num - 10 if 30 > num > 20 else ('1' + str(num[1:])) if num >= 30 else num for num in leftover]
```

Comment: there is a slight typo `('1' + str(num[1:]))` it should be `('1' + str(num)[1:])`